# How do i install additional packages for Xcode on OSX Lion to allow MacPorts to work

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, macports

When I try and install MacPorts it complains 
'Xcode is not installed, or was installed with UNIX Development (10.5+) or Command Line Support (10.4) deselected.'

I do have Xcode installed from the Appstore so I guess I just have to install these extra parts but how ?

Ive read a couple of questions on Stack Overflow about this but I think the answers must be outdated as they do notmake sense for me, I do not have an Xcode dmg I can reinstall from, and I can't see anything useful in /Developer either, or any preferences within Xcode itself.

I only want Xcode for the purposes of using Macports so I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Oh man totally confused now becaue AppStore says I have installed Xcode 4.1 but when I run Xcode from Developer it says it is version 3.2.6 , and I cannot find Xcode 4.1 anywhere !

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted.. seriously? own to your downvotes folks. I wouldn't +1 the question but i feel obliged to counter vote here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably got Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store. In that case, you haven't got Xcode 4.1 installed. However, you now have an Xcode installer in your Applications directory.

Spotlight should find it in any case.

Comment: Ah, yes my problem was that I did in fact have Xcode 3.2.6 already installed in /Developer and I assumed that was the XCode I had got from Mac Store, installing it now will mark you correct answer if that then allows MacPorts to install.

Comment: Thanks XCode installation has actually hang at the end, but seems to have worked anyway, or at least macPorts can now be installed.

Answer (score 5):

The command line tools aren't included in the default install of Xcode anymore.
Goto the Xcode Preferences --> Downloads Pane --> click the Install button beside "Command Line Tools".
If you don't have Xcode installed you can get the command line tools separately as explained here..

http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/06/install-gcc-without-xcode-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

The App Store installs the XCode installer, not Xcode itself. The installer is in your applications folder. Run that.

Answer (score 0):

Today, 16 Feb 2012, when I installed Xcode 4 from the App Store, there was no Setup. Just the app installed, because it was Xcode 4.3 !

Make sure that you install Xcode 4.2 with UNIX Devel. to MacPorts works!

To get the Xcode 4.2 go to https://developer.apple.com.