# Installing pygame on OS X 10.6.8 with EPD enthought 7.2

Tags: python, macos, pygame, enthought

I am trying to install Pygame on Mac OS X 10.6.8 using the Enthought 7.2 64 bit python distribution.

The pygame installer doesn't see that I have Enthought installed and doesn't work.

I then manually installed SDL, SDL_image, SDL_mixer, and SDL_ttf frameworks myself and the libjpeg and libpng libraries.

An attempt to install pygame then via `pip` generates a massive amount of errors :

```
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/imageext.o

In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_main.h:26,

                 from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL.h:30,

                 from src/pygame.h:106,

                 from src/imageext.c:47:

/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_stdinc.h:155:24: error: begin_code.h: No such file or directory

In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_main.h:26,

                 from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL.h:30,

                 from src/pygame.h:106,

                 from src/imageext.c:47:

/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_stdinc.h:370: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
```

And 40-50 more variations on this theme. I was quite happy with Enthought as it worked out of the box, so I would like to prevent starting from zero again with macports or brew. Anybody any ideas?

**EDIT**
Since nobody had a clue, I started over with Lion, Xcode 4.3, the commandline tools from apple, [this so tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420894/852224)(!), and a fresh macports python environment centered around python version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I don't quite get why you are trying to install with that other thingy, but if you are trying to install it and are getting problems, I suggest you uninstall Enthought 7.2 64 bit and then reinstall it when you have installed pygame.